# Unable to save password for oracle.com website

Tags: website, password-management

When I tried to login to oracle.com today, neither Firefox not Chrome could save the password for the account (or pre-filled the fields).

Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intentional behaviour by Oracle, which has been discussed in their [forums](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=677715&tstart=105). Back in [2005](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1020150&#1032585) they disabled auto-login, using **autocomplete="off"**.

This is obeyed by [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion). Personally I use the LastPass extension for my passwords which ignores this setting and happily remembers and populates my password.

Comment: Ah, found it, now. I was looking at the field but it's on the `form` element.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing problems with this using Opera as well.  I think it may be related to the changes Oracle has made with re-directing a lot of the content on Sun's web site after buying them.  Hopefully they'll have this fixed soon.

Comment: I would understand that it doesn't find my *old* password but why don't I get a "Save password for this site" dialog when I log in?

Comment: That's a strange one.  The first thought that comes to mind for me there is that the remembered passwords database might contain some corruption, but you've already tried two different web browsers.  It's certainly possible that Oracle has figured out some way to prevent the "Remember password" feature from activating in multiple web browsers.